# Avoiding invisible non printable characters in text editor

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

The user can copy a [non printable character](https://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html) and paste it inside a text editor (i.e: `TEdit`).

After doing this, the `TEdit`'s `Text` will contain the non printable character, but the user will not be able to see it.

---

**Example:**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Clipbrd;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if(Length(Edit1.Text) > 5) then
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Ord(Edit1.Text[6])))
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Clipboard.AsText := 'Hello' + #31 + 'World';
end;

end.
```

Pasting inside the `Edit1` and pressing the `Button1` will show that the fifth character is `#31`

[image: showmessage dialog displaying 31 as the fifth character of the]

---

I don't like that the user can't distinguish between a `TEdit` having `Text = 'Hello' + #31 + 'World'` from another editor having `Text = 'HelloWorld'`.

For this reason I would like to do one of the following two things, preferrable the first:

- Display the non printable characters (As *Notepad++* does by enabling the "Menu View → Show Symbol → Show All Characters" option: [image: screenshot of notepad++ displaying a non printable character])
- Avoid that the editor accepts non printable characters

Comment: You could sanitise the text you paste into the control.

Comment: An edit control does not have any option to show/hide/display differently for any text part. You can loop through the characters in your string and discard the ones that you don't like depending on their category. The one in your example is a control character: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Character_Manipulation_Routines

Comment: What is the consequence of doing nothing? I can't really see any scenario where this should be treated as anything other than the user's problem. Unless of course you are writing a text editor.

Comment: You could use the edit OnChange event to analyse edit content and remove any unwanted character.

Comment: Your next challenge is probably a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph

Answer (score 0):

You'd have a hard time modifying how the edit control renders the text. As a compromise consider using a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font instead of the default one - that should display the same width for every character, even zero-length spaces.